# Flex mobile: collapsible panel

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, panel

I'm building a Flex 4.6 mobile application with Flash Builder from Adobe and I want to implement some sort of collapsible panels. I found some frameworks but they are all for desktop application and are not mobile compatible. I also tried to convert those to mobile but didn't succeed in it.

Are there any mobile frameworks that can help me? or is there some kind of alternative?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a framework that does this but an alternative is to implement your own collapsible panel. [Here](http://www.iwobanas.com/2009/09/creating-collapsible-panel-in-flex-4/) is a tutorial with [source](http://www.iwobanas.com/wp-content/uploads/collapsible_panel_01/srcview/index.html). You declare transitions for the in and out animations, and listen to an activating action e.g. button click. You bind the transition to the panel via the 'target' property of the transition.